# ConTeXt: Behaviour of nested textbackground

Tags: context

I would like to use different text frames that are able to break across pages. Based on the answer to [a qestion about framed text and page boundaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225610/framed-text-and-pageboundary), I'm using `textbackground` to do this. However, I'm having trouble interpreting how `textbackground` behaves when it's nested.

Example:

```
\definetextbackground
  [BoxA]
  [leftoffset=1cm,
   rightoffset=1cm,
   topoffset=1cm,
   bottomoffset=1cm,
   location=paragraph,
   background=color,
   backgroundcolor=yellow]

\definetextbackground
  [BoxB]
  [leftoffset=2cm,
   rightoffset=1cm,
   topoffset=1cm,
   bottomoffset=1cm,
   location=paragraph,
   background=color,
   backgroundcolor=red]

\starttext

\startBoxA
BoxA independent does what I expect
\stopBoxA

\startBoxB
BoxB independent does what I expect
\stopBoxB

\startBoxA
\startBoxB
BoxB within BoxA does not do what I expect
\stopBoxB
\stopBoxA

\stoptext
```

[image: nested textbackground]

I would have expected the nested example to have a red paragraph block within a yellow paragraph block, but respecting the specified offsets, or perhaps only the red block to show up.

What's happening here and is there a way for both offsets to add up together to generate a block of yellow, with a padded block of red inside?

[image: expected nested textbackground]

Comment: Looks like you cannot have two nested boxes both anchored at `paragraph`.  On the other hand I wouldn't know what to expect in that case.  Your expectation is most likely wrong.  Better ask the Metafun experts on the mailing list: ntg-context@ntg.nl